# IOS Segemnting a video

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, avplayer

I want to segment a video into 9 sections jumble the sections about and then play them together. I am currently trying to use AVPlayer to do this. I can get the sections to load on the simulator but only the first 4 will load on the actual phone. I guess the resources are topping out.

My question is: Is AVPlayer the best framework to use for this (as it seems a waste to create a player item, player and playerlayer for each segment(Which I think is why the resources are topping out)) or is there a lower framework I can use to load one video and display certain segments of it on certain sreas of the screen?

Thanks